# Arduino MIDI controller won't stop crashing VirtualDJ

Tags: arduino, crash, midi

I've decided to make my own MIDI controller for the Virtual DJ program. For this I first bought the Arduino Pro Mico and wrote a test program. I tested it with FL Studio and after a few problems that I was able to solve, it worked perfectly. I immediately opened Virtual DJ to test it there, but every time I connect the Arduino Pro Mico it just goes white and dosn't respond anymore until I unplug the arduino again.

I've already tried:

- Use another pro micro
- Testing on my laptop => same error
- Rewrite the program

I also tried to load a completely different program on it and then it didn't crash. I think every time I use the "MIDIUSB.h" library, this error occurs.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you monitor what is being sent and received by the device? (if on a Mac,  try Midi Monitor) Just a guess - maybe there is a MIDI message "feedback loop" and the device and the program get bogged down with echoing messages to each other?  It works OK with FL Studio but not another program? See if you can turn off MIDI pass-thru or MIDI echo in Virtual DJ? Still just guessing. Good luck!

Comment: The problem isn't that the controller is sending too much data, or anything at all. I tried testing it without any code at all in the loop or setup function, same result. I managed to get it to work with the programm 'Mixxx', yet I still hope it will work with virtualdj at some point..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. I switched the device from micro to Leonardo, because the pro micro is in reality a smaller version of the Leonardo.